# Gulp Browsersync does not see current connections and does not reload

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, livereload

I am trying to run browsersync so I could Live Reload the changes in the browser.

**Problem No. 1:** 
Connecting to the browsersync dashboard, `http://localhost:3001/`, I don't see any connection being listed under **Current Connections**.

**Problem No. 2:** 
Reload function used in the `gulpfile.js` is not really working on the browser, however, it does get triggered in my CLI, which shows the next anytime I commit a change in my text editor:

`Watch hit
[BS] Reloading Browsers...`

Out of the next:

```
gulp.watch("app/**/*.html").on("change", function () {

    console.log("Watch hit");
    browserSync.reload();

});
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload      = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('serve', function () {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "app/",
            proxy: 'localhost:3000'
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("app/**/*.html").on("change", function () {

        console.log("Watch hit");
        browserSync.reload();

    });

});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

So, honestly at first look everything looks like working fine. But I should be missing something.

**p.s.** I don't have LiveReload Chrome plugin working, or at least I don't think it is working.

**BrowserSync Sync Options**

- **CodeSync** Reload or Inject files they change
- **Clicks** Mirror clicks across devices
- **Scroll** Mirror scroll position across devices
- **Forms**: submit Form Submissions will be synced
- **Forms**: inputs Text inputs (including text-areas) will be synced
- **Forms**: toggles

Answer (score 0):

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

note the create() at the end.